# Query on database or calculate with code?

Tags: php, mongodb, performance

I want to calculate the sum (Or any math operation) of many (row/document)s. Which one is the best practice for doing this? using query or loop with code?

Query example (mongo):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:fieldOne,result:{$sum:fieldTwo}}}])
```

Code (php):

```
$result = db['myDb']->collection->find([]);
$sum = 0;
foreach($result as $doc)
   $sum += $doc->fieldTwo;
```

Comment: Using a query will prevent sending all of these lines back to the code...I prefer the query in this case

Comment: Query will give you a batter performance at run time while foreach loop will take more time.

Comment: The answer is it depends on details not present in your question. What is the utilization of the mongo instance? What is the utilization of the backend server? Same physical hardware, same internal network, or across continents? In general, perform as much filtering as possible in the database. That is a generalization and not an answer or fact. I can easily build configurations where backend processing is faster. It just depends.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to do as much as possible on server side and keep only cosmetics for clients.

If you create compound index on:

```
  db.collection.createIndex({fieldOne:1,fieldTwo:1})
```

your aggregation query executed on the server side can be extremely faster, and you can prove that executing it as follow:

```
 db.collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$fieldOne", result:{$sum:"$fieldTwo"}} }],{hint:{fieldOne:1,fieldTwo:1}})
```

which will show you:

```
                            "executionStats" : {
                                    "executionSuccess" : true,
                                    "nReturned" : XXXX,
                                    "executionTimeMillis" : 1,
                                    "totalKeysExamined" : XXXX,
                                    "totalDocsExamined" : 0
```

That will prove you are using only the already in memory index for the task ...

P.S.
Dont forget to [hint()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#hint-an-index) the mongoDB queryPlanner to use the index since by default for group stages mongoDB will not select the index ...